# Image Position/Orientation not written when saving itkImage as DICOM

Tags: c++, dicom, itk, gdcm

I have a 3D volume as `itkImage<unsigned char, 3>` and want to save it as DICOM series. Saving the series works so far, but the metadata tags "Image Position Patient" and "Image Orientation Patient" are not saved in the dicom file. All other tags are saved correctly.

If I print the metadata dictionary to the console these tags are printed correctly. When I open the files in ITK-SNAP these two tags are missin.

> 0010|0010 Patient
>
> 0010|0020 12345
>
> 0020|0032 0\0\0
>
> 0020|0037 1\0\0\0\1\0

This is the part of the code where these tags are stored in the metadata. I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ipa/669d5756a83f503336d0ee1d654efaa3) with a working example.

```
UC3ImageType::PointType position;
UC3ImageType::IndexType index;
index[0] = 0;
index[1] = 0;
index[2] = f;
image->TransformIndexToPhysicalPoint(index, position);
value.str("");
value << position[0] << "\\" << position[1] << "\\" << position[2];
itk::EncapsulateMetaData<std::string>(*dictionary, "0020|0032", value.str());
value.str("");
value << position[2];
itk::EncapsulateMetaData<std::string>(*dictionary, "0020|1041", value.str());

itk::EncapsulateMetaData<std::string>(*dictionary, "0020|0037", "1\\0\\0\\0\\1\\0");
```

What's wrong with this code? Are there other tags that are required, such that these tags are saved as well?

Comment: I believe this used to be a bug in `ITK`. Do you have a really old version? Although I have not checked recently if it reappeared..

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks a lot, I'm using version 4.6.1

Comment: Both seem to work in ITK-4.9.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve the problem by specifying a different SOP Class UID. By default it's using [Secondary Capture IOD](http://dicom.nema.org/dicom/2013/output/chtml/part03/sect_A.8.html) and I changed it to [Ultrasound Multi Frame](http://dicom.nema.org/dicom/2013/output/chtml/part03/sect_A.7.html), which is also more apropriate for my image. Now the Image Orientation/Position are stored correctly.

```
const std::string SOP_CLASS_UID = "0008|0016";
const std::string US_MULTIFRAME_UID = "1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.3.1";
itk::EncapsulateMetaData<std::string>(*dictionary, SOP_CLASS_UID, US_MULTIFRAME_UID);
```

However, to me it's still strange, that there is no warning or exception when a metadata tag is not saved due to whatever reason.

Comment: please do report a bug against GDCM. It should not write out IPP and IOP attributes in the case of `Ultrasound Multi Frame`

Comment: @malat: what's wrong with saving the IPP and IOP in this case?

Comment: where did you see that [`Ultrasound Multi Frame IOD`](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_A.7.4.html) includes a definition for IOP/IPP ?